# What's the word after Gucci and Hermes?

Tags: orthography

Here is the link of the video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C9Y5i77gpwY

And in about 0:07, there is an expression

> Rocking the next Gucci ? or Hermes ?

and I can't figure out what words should follow "Gucci" and "Hermes"

Comment: "and" should be "or"

Answer (score 2):

The word is "line", it is short for [product line](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/product-line.asp) which the Investopedia website defines as

> A group of related products all marketed under a single brand name that is sold by the same company.

"The next Gucci and Hermes lines" are the absolutely latest collections of clothing and accessories from those fashion houses, by implication so new that they are not generally available.

If you're into that sort of stuff you'll be impressed that the people with those items have both the wealth and connections to obtain them. If you're not into it you won't know, won't notice and won't care.

Comment: But I think there is one word following the "Gucci"(which is "line" you mentioned in your post) and another one following the "Hermes"

Comment: It sounds like "the next Gucci line or Aramis tie".

Comment: @GEdgar: I think it's *Hermès* tie—the speaker is clearly trying to sound like she's pronouncing that word in French.  (*Air mess* would be the closet phonemes in English, and she comes close to that.  But I think she's using slightly different vowels in an attempt to sound Frencher.)

Comment: @PeterShor Wouldn't that be that ***she*** was attempting to sound **French-*esse*? :)** The French vowels of *Hermès* aren't *too* alien for English, though one of its consonants sure is: [ɛʁmɛs]. For speakers with the *merry–marry–Mary* merger, that ought to be any of [eɪ̯ɹˈmɛs], [eɹˈmɛs], [ɛɹˈmɛs]. To me it nearly sounds like she’s **voicing** (‽) her final /s/ into /z/ for no apparent reason — but some effort, given the unvoiced plosive coming right up in *tie*, phonemic /tai/ ᴀᴋᴀ /taj/, so with phonetic diphthongs [tʰʌɪ̯], [tʰɐɪ̯], or [tʰäɪ̯] depending on dialect, speaker, and utterance.

Comment: Actually, regarding these brands, I don't think it would be "product line" but rather "fashion line."  The fashion industry refers to its lines as "fashion lines," not "product lines."

Comment: @BenjaminHarman Yes, you're probably right, but the principle is still the same.